# Better way of passing Mongodb query data to Pug

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I am looking for a better way of passing data to my index.js file in a webdev application. Note I really only have about a month of webdev experience so this is likely due to lack of experience. here is my software flow:

1. I query data in a route handler before the page is rendered. I then pass this data to the rendered page (note i need to keep some of the key-vals hidden. However aggregation works).

   exports.getPlotView = async(req, res, next) =>{
   //grab the module to query from, stored as var.testModel
   const qParse = new PlotQueryParse(req.query).parseObj();
   // console.log(qParse)
   // const testblockName = qParse.testblock+"Name" ;
   // const limitName = qParse.limitname;

   ```
    const aggregationObj = {$match:
                                {'jobId':qParse.jobId, '<key2>':<val2>, "<key>":"<val>"}
                            }

    const data = await qParse.testModel.aggregate([aggregationObj]);
    console.log(data[0])
    const dataString = JSON.stringify(data[0]);
    //parse the url to make the query
    res.status(200).render('testPlotView', {
        pageHeader: "Test",
        subHead: "Test summary",
        IPn: "IPn",
        inData:dataString
    });
   ```

   }
2. data is passed to pug template. The template uses this as a hidden  element

   ```
    extends base
    block content
        div.hide_data #{inData}

        div#dataviz
   ```
3. now in my index.js script (listens for evenets), the data is loaded from the page and then stored for post processing. I would like to directly access the variable instead of having it hidden then accessing the DOM element.

   window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   if(window.location.href.includes('testplotdata')){
   console.log('its a me mario')
   //if we are in a test plot data page, lets plot
   var jsonObject = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('.hide_data').innerHTML);
   console.log(jsonObject['testData'])

   ```
    //post processing code ....

    }
   ```

   })

Again, I want a way to grab my queried data without saving it as a DOM element then accessing it in my external event listener script.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `var myData` contain all the data pre-populated by pug? Then why can't you access it directly in your JS script?

Comment: @SonNguyen Hi Son. I made a mistake in the original post. I have edited it. I am using an external script to process the variable. Is there a way I can directly access the value passed in via render in my external processing script?

Comment: I posted answer so you see fully formatted code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing data in HTML, add inline script to your template to store it in a global variable instead. So replace `div.hide_data #{inData}` with:

```
script.
   var inData = !{inData};   // inData passed by backend must be a string
                             // representing a valid JS object (JSON will do)
```

Now you just access `inData` as a ready native object in your external script (which you need to make sure load after the above script, putting it at the end of `<body>` will do)

```
// No need: var jsonObject = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('.hide_data').innerHTML);
console.log(inData);    // Go ahead with the data
```